# Adding objects as keys in Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using a object as key and number as value but getting the below error in line. Any help ?

> dict[a] =  1

:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "detect_hung_connections.py", line 24, in <module>
    dict = {a:1}
TypeError: __hash__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

My Code is as follows:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __hash__(self,a,b):
        return hash(self.a,self.b)

    def __eq__(self,other):
        return (self.a,self.b) == (other.a,other.b)

dict ={}
a =  A("aa","bb")

dict[a] = 1

b = A("aa","bb")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature of `A.__hash__` should not take any extra arguments.

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash((self.a,self.b))
```

Comment: This is still passing two arguments; `hash` takes only one.  I got this to fail about 3 seconds before your answer appeared on my screen.  :-)

Comment: @Prune Check the parentheses. It is passing a single tuple to `hash()`.

Comment: <insert head-slap>.  Sorry.  Glad I didn't down-vote this -- it's more generalized than my concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling hash with the entire object and (redundantly) its two attributes.  You can use only a single value to hash.  Try this, perhaps:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.a + self.b)
```

This at least passes execution.